# DO I need Bonferroni correction for ANCOVA analysis repeated 10 times?

Tags: bonferroni

I have 2 groups, and are comparing them using T Test, and ANCOVA (with covariates), and am repeating this with 10 dependent variables (9 subtest scores and 1 overall test score. Do i have to use bonferroni correction for ANCOVA?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!